# Arista EOS VM stuck during booting

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, kvm

I am trying to boot Arista EOS image on Ubuntu 12.04. Qemu-kvm package is installed.
But there is no command like `qemu-kvm` so i am using `kvm` command.

The vm gets created, starts to boot but is stuck at the boot stage

```
root@addanother-dr:~/qemu# kvm -nographic -vga std -cdrom Aboot-veos-qemu-serial-2.0.6.iso -boot d -hda EOS-4.9.0-veos.vmdk -usb -m 1024 -net nic,macaddr=52:54:00:01:02:03,model=e1000 -net nic,macaddr=52:54:00:01:02:04,model=e1000 -net nic,macaddr=52:54:00:01:02:05,model=e1000 -net nic,macaddr=52:54:00:01:02:06,model=e1000 -net nic,macaddr=52:54:00:01:02:07,model=e1000
Warning: vlan 0 is not connected to host network

ISOLINUX 4.02 2010-07-21  Copyright (C) 1994-2010 H. Peter Anvin et al
Loading linux....
Loading initrd....ready.


Aboot 2.0.6-689124


Press Control-C now to enter Aboot shell
Booting flash:EOS-veos.swi
Starting new kernel
```

If someone could please tell me what may be wrong.
I am running 32-bit Ubuntu system.

Answer (score 2):

This is indicative of the VM being unable to find the virtual hard disk (.vmdk) file. Check your storage settings and make sure the .vmdk for that VM exists.

Your command line shows where to find Aboot, which is the bootloader for vEOS. You also need to specify a vdmk file for the vEOS hard disk. From the vEOS README:

```
qemu-kvm \
   -nographic \
   -vga std \
   -cdrom Aboot-qemu-serial-2.0.6.iso \
   -boot d \
   -hda EOS-4.10.2-veos.vmdk \
   -usb \
   -m 1024 \
   -net
```

This can help if you decide to go with VirtualBox. From within vEOS, the symptoms are the same:

http://www.gad.net/Blog/2012/10/27/building-a-virtual-lab-with-arista-veos-and-virtualbox/

Comment: I have specified vmdk file '-hda EOS-4.9.0-veos.vmdk' option in my question. So probably unable to find vmdk file is not the problem. I believed that this error was due to some 32/64bit system issue. Probably the image was 64Bit which i was trying to run on a 32Bit environment. Though VMWare was able to run it but not KVM. But finally i had everything running smoothly on 64Bit system with KVM.

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Sorry - didn't see that - it scrolled off the side of the page. Glad you got it worked out.